# Выделение части ячейки в таблице (делегаты)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, делегаты

У меня в таблице ячейки могут иметь два значения (иконки), которые могут отдельно выделяться.

Сделал делегат и для состояния выделения определял на какой половине ячейки находится курсор и менял положение рамки выделения,
но такая реализация оказалась с тормозами -- при переключении внутри ячейки видна задержка и если после клика на одну половину переместить курсор, то выделение может оказаться на другой половине

Мне нужна возможность выделения части ячейки с возможностью определять что выделено. В рабочем проекте использую: `QTableView` и `QAbstractTableModel`

Привожу код.

**celldelegate.h/cpp**

```
#ifndef CELLDELEGATE_H
#define CELLDELEGATE_H
 
 
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
 
class CellDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    public:
        CellDelegate(QWidget* parent = 0);
 
    protected:
        void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
};
 
 
#endif // CELLDELEGATE_H


// ----------------------------------

#include "celldelegate.h"
#include <QPainter>
#include <QDebug>
 
 
CellDelegate::CellDelegate(QWidget* parent)
    : QStyledItemDelegate(parent) {
 
}
 
void CellDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const {
    // Цвет выделения полупрозрачный, чтобы были видно что в ячейке
    QStyleOptionViewItem itemOption(option);
    initStyleOption(&itemOption, index);
 
    if (itemOption.state & QStyle::State_Selected) {
        QPoint pos = dynamic_cast <QWidget*> (parent())->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos());
        QRect& rect = itemOption.rect;
        bool leftSide = (rect.x() + (rect.width() / 2)) > pos.x();
 
        if (leftSide) {
            rect.setWidth(rect.width() / 2);
        } else {
            rect.setX(rect.x() + rect.width() / 2);
        }
 
        QColor color = itemOption.palette.color(QPalette::Highlight);
        color.setAlpha(180);
        itemOption.palette.setColor(QPalette::Highlight, color);
    }
 
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, itemOption, index);
}
```

**widget.h/cpp**

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H
 
#include <QWidget>
#include <QTableWidget>
 
 
class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
 
    public:
        Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
 
    private:
        QTableWidget table;
};
 
#endif // WIDGET_H    

// ---------------------------

#include "widget.h"
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include "celldelegate.h"
 
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    layout->addWidget(&table);
 
    table.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectItems);
    table.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
    table.setItemDelegate(new CellDelegate(table.viewport()));
 
    table.setRowCount(3);
    table.setColumnCount(3);
 
    setLayout(layout);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**. Вариант с определением положения через наследник таблицы.

Тоже не работает и даже появился интересный баг: при клике сначала на одна сторону выделяется, потом другая.

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QMouseEvent>


class TableWidget: public QTableWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        QPoint clickedPos;

    protected:
        void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
            clickedPos = event->pos();

            QTableWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
        }
};




class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);

    private:
        TableWidget table;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H





#include "celldelegate.h"
#include <QPainter>
#include <QDebug>
#include "widget.h"


CellDelegate::CellDelegate(QWidget* parent)
    : QStyledItemDelegate(parent) {

}

void CellDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const {
    // Цвет выделения полупрозрачный, чтобы были видно что в ячейке
    QStyleOptionViewItem itemOption(option);
    initStyleOption(&itemOption, index);

    if (itemOption.state & QStyle::State_Selected) {
//        QPoint pos = dynamic_cast <QWidget*> (parent())->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos());
        QPoint pos = dynamic_cast <TableWidget*> (parent())->clickedPos;
        QRect& rect = itemOption.rect;
        bool leftSide = (rect.x() + (rect.width() / 2)) > pos.x();

        if (leftSide) {
            rect.setWidth(rect.width() / 2);
        } else {
            rect.setX(rect.x() + rect.width() / 2);
        }

        QColor color = itemOption.palette.color(QPalette::Highlight);
        color.setAlpha(180);
        itemOption.palette.setColor(QPalette::Highlight, color);
    }

    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, itemOption, index);
}
```

---

Большая часть проблем была решена, но осталась еще одна -- странная перерисовка ячейки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При проверке того, какая из половин ячеек была выделена, Вам необходимо опираться на координаты клика, а не координаты текущего положения курсора. Придётся унаследоваться от `QTableView` и переопределять события мыши. Затем, необходимо будет передавать координаты последнего клика непосредственно в делегат и сохранять их там для последующего проведения проверки при перерисовке элемента. Отчасти этот подход снизит и потребление ресурсов.

Comment: @alexis031182 делал так -- ловил клик на сигнал clicked, запоминал и в делегате через родителя получал указатель на view, у которого брал тот pos. Делал также и для, кажется, событий mousePressEvent/mouseReleaseEvent тоже фигня вышла

Comment: @alexis031182, посмотрите -- сделал как вы предложили, но это не помогло

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я скопировал Ваш код первой версии и запустил у себя. Как оказалось, Вы были правы, происходит самопроизвольное переключение текущего региона в ячейке при смещении курсора. Очевидно, что опираться просто на текущие координаты никак нельзя.

Тогда я взял Ваш второй вариант кода на пробу, где, как мне показалось, всё было сделано верно. И действительно, момент с самопроизвольным перескакиванием текущего региона оказался исправлен. Оставалось одно - после щелчка мыши по иному региону вместо текущего переключение производилось чрезвычайно медленно. Было очевидно, что событие на перерисовку ячейки поступает с опозданием и связано оно даже не с фактом щелчка мыши, а скорее с каким-то иным событием. Соответственно осталось одно - подсказать виджету о том, что он должен по щелчку перерисовать конкретную ячейку. Сделать это можно так:

```
void TableView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
    clickedPos = event->pos();

    QModelIndex index = indexAt(clickedPos);
    if(index.isValid()) update(index);

    QTableView::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Помогло :) а как быть при клике между соседними ячейками -- при клике сначала подсвечивается половина области потом та, на которую был клик?

Comment: Не знаю, я пощёлкал, у меня довольно быстро перерисовка идёт, трудно заметить то, о чём Вы говорите. Но я конечно понимаю, что событий на перерисовку ячейки происходит несколько. Это и собственно при селекте ячейки, и при клике - это то, которое вызываем через апдейт. Возможно стоит усложнить подход и не давать при нажатии кнопки мыши отправлять события перерисовки, и как только отпустили, то только тогда её и производить. Или пересмотреть поведение `QItemSelectionModel`.

Comment: обновил вопрос гифкой, показывающей проблему, которую описывал :)

Comment: У меня линукс, такого эффекта нет. Клетка выделяется в любом случае вся, а уже внутреннее выделение региона в ячейке обрамляется отдельной рамкой, поэтому выглядит нормально. У Вас же, я думаю, эффект первоначального выделения связан с тем, что событий обновлений ячейки несколько. Пробуйте поэкспериментировать с `QItemSelectionModel`. Например, можно вообще убрать селект как таковой, а ориентироваться только на `currentIndex()`.

Comment: Хорошо, поиграюсь с этим )

Answer (score 2):

Прикладываю [решение](http://www.prog.org.ru/index.php?topic=30262.msg223417#msg223417), в котором все найденные баги были решены.

Главное в нем – делегат и вся работа в нем:

**h:**

```
#ifndef CELLDELEGATE_H
#define CELLDELEGATE_H

#include <QStyledItemDelegate>

class CellDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    public:
        CellDelegate(QWidget* parent = 0);
        bool eventFilter( QObject * obj, QEvent * event );

    protected:
        void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;

    QPersistentModelIndex mIndex;
    bool mLeftSide;
};


#endif // CELLDELEGATE_H
```

**cpp:**

```
#include "celldelegate.h"
#include <QtWidgets>


CellDelegate::CellDelegate(QWidget* parent)
    : QStyledItemDelegate(parent) {

}

bool CellDelegate::eventFilter( QObject * obj, QEvent * event )
{
    switch (event->type()) {
        case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:  
        case QEvent::MouseMove:
            {
                QTableView * tbl = dynamic_cast<QTableView *> (obj);
                if (!tbl) tbl = dynamic_cast<QTableView *> (obj->parent());
                if (!tbl) break;
                QMouseEvent * me = static_cast<QMouseEvent *> (event);
                QModelIndex index = tbl->indexAt(me->pos());
                if (!index.isValid()) break;
                bool left = me->pos().x() < tbl->visualRect(index).center().x();
                if ((index == mIndex) && (left == mLeftSide)) break;
                mIndex = index;
                mLeftSide = left;
                tbl->viewport()->update();
            }
            break;
    }
    return false;
}

void CellDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const {
    // Цвет выделения полупрозрачный, чтобы были видно что в ячейке
    QStyleOptionViewItem itemOption(option);
    initStyleOption(&itemOption, index);

    if ((itemOption.state & QStyle::State_Selected) && (index == mIndex)) {
        QRect& rect = itemOption.rect;
        if (mLeftSide) 
            rect.setWidth(rect.width() / 2);
        else 
            rect.setX(rect.x() + rect.width() / 2);

        QColor color = itemOption.palette.color(QPalette::Highlight);
        color.setAlpha(180);
        itemOption.palette.setColor(QPalette::Highlight, color);
    }

    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, itemOption, index);
}
```

---

**И подключение, без которого не будет работать:**

```
CellDelegate * delegate = new CellDelegate(table.viewport());
table.setItemDelegate(delegate);
table.viewport()->installEventFilter(delegate);
```

Comment: Да, хорошее решение использовать фильтр событий и постоянные индексы. Igors респект :)